# scala-maven-plugin compile failed For artifact {org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.11:null:jar}

Tags: scala, maven-3

Seems that something has changed in the scala maven repository cause I get a new error for a project that worked before. If I am running on my own machine it will work since I have .m2 folder that has the missing jar, but when running on a new machine (circle ci) it fails.

LOG:

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.0.0:compile (scala-compile) on project my-project-name: Execution scala-compile of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.0.0:compile failed: For artifact {org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.11:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

The pom looks as follows:

```
        <!-- scala plugins -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--<recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>-->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I think this is a new issue - if someone has a workaround I will appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Problem was fixed by adding version to maven plugin:

```
    <!-- scala plugins -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <!--<recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>-->
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>scala-compile</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: This particular version works where 4.0.0 did not work for me.  It used to work without having to explicitly state the version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin> 
<groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
<execution>
......
.......
</executions>
</plugin>
```

"Added version tag"

Answer (score -1):

I hav encountered the same problem, Thanks Ehud Lev for sharing his solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you have the same problem, consider upvoting the original question. You posted your comment as an answer--check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for tips on giving helpful answers.